# How to find all commits by user to *any* repo in bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I have many repos, in which I need to find some commit I made a very long time ago. Due to reasons, I don't know which repos I have commits in, and when I did those commits.

I could go over them one by one, looking for when I did commits.

Is there some API or UI to just see all commits by a user, to any repo, sorted by time?

Comment: The *Git* answer is: "I don't look anywhere but one repository on your computer: clone all your repos, and then run one Git command per repo to search them all on your own laptop". There might be a better-for-you Bitbucket web site or API answer, though.

Answer (score 5):

You could use git's `-C` option with each of your repo paths to run git commands in them. Depending how your repos are locally organized, you may want to change how the paths are discovered. Change `username` to your committer email address. The pattern just needs to be unique, so you can probably leave off `@example.com`. Change the `--before` option as needed.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for d in ~/path-to-repos/*/.git; do
    r=${d%.git}
    echo "$r"
    git -C "$r" log \
        --committer=username \
        --before=2013 \
        --reverse \
        --pretty='format:%h  %cd  %s'
done
```

You might want to experiment with git log's `--pretty` options.

Comment: This forces me to clone everything, I was looking to avoid that. Or, did you mean I can do that directly on the repos inside bitbucket somehow?

Comment: You would need to clone them. I missed the part where you want  to do this _in_ Bitbucket.

Comment: Looks like you can get a listing of repos in Bitbucket using an API which would help automate cloning them all.

Comment: It might be good to add `--no-pager` option before the `log` command.